# Two y Axis in Highcharter in R

Tags: r, highcharts

I would like to make a line chart containing one x axis sharing two y axis, one on the left side and the second one on the right of the plot **in R**.

I found many examples on how to do this but I don't manage to reproduce it in R with the package "highcharter".

Here are the examples :

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/opposite/

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes

Here what I have done so far :

```
g <- highchart()%>%
hc_xAxis(categories = c("2016-01-01","2016-02-01","2016-03-01","2016-04-01","2016-05-01","2016-06-01","2016-07-01","2016-08-01","2016-09-01","2016-10-01"))%>%
hc_yAxis(
  list(title = list(text = "Yaxis1")),
  list(title = list(text = "Yaxis2"), opposite = TRUE)
)%>%
hc_series(
  list(yAxis = 0, data = c(7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3), name = "Data1"),
  list(yAxis = 1, data = c(8.0, 7.9, 10.5, 15.5, 19.2, 22.5, 28.2, 23.5, 21.3, 14.3), name = "Data2")
)
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the highcharter official website there is a demo with two axis:

http://jkunst.com/highcharter/highcharts.html#highcharts-home-page-demo

[image]

You need to use `hc_yAxis_multiples` in this case:

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_yAxis_multiples(
    list(lineWidth = 3),
    list(showLastLabel = FALSE, opposite = TRUE)
  ) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = rnorm(10)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = rexp(10), type = "spline", yAxis = 1)
```

Comment: How do you reference YAxis 0 or 1 to do formating in `hc_yAxis`? I.e. `labels_YAxis0 = list(format = "{value} mm")`

Comment: Is there a similar function for the x-axis? I'm looking to introduce a secondary axis for a horizontal stacked bar chart...

Answer (score 5):

The 'two-axis' demo mentioned isn't on the web-site any more!

Here is an example derived from `jbkunst`'s own help documentation `?hc_yAxis_multiples`

In particular, it shows how to place titles on those separate y-axes...

```r
aapl <- quantmod::getSymbols("AAPL", 
                             src = "yahoo",
                             from = "2020-01-01",
                             auto.assign = FALSE
)

# Plot prices and volume with relative height.
highchart(type = "stock") %>%
    hc_title(text = "AAPLE") %>%
    hc_yAxis_multiples(list(title = list(text = "Price"), opposite = FALSE),
                       list(showLastLabel = FALSE, opposite = TRUE, title = list(text = "Volume"))) %>%
    hc_add_series(aapl, yAxis = 0, showInLegend = FALSE) %>%
    hc_add_series(aapl[, "AAPL.Volume"], yAxis = 1, type = "column", showInLegend = FALSE)
```

[image: multiple Y axis labelling]