# Multiple y-axes in shiny app w/ highcharter

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny

I'm trying to render a graph in a shiny app using highcharter that shares an x-axis (days) but has multiple y-axes (a percent and a count). After some research it seems like I should use the 'hc_yAxis_multiples' method. On the left y-axis, I have % displayed. On the right y-axis, I want the count displayed. There is a line graph that is based on the left y-axis (%), and a stacked bar graph that is displayed based on the right y-axis.

I have been able to overlay the two graphs, but the bar chart portion based on the right y-axis is not formatted to the corresponding y-axis. Based on what I have been looking at, it seems like something like this would produce a result that I want:

```
##This first block is to show what the data types of the variables I'm using are and what the structure of my df looks like
df$inbox_rate <- df$total_inbox / df$total_volume
df$inbox_rate <- round((df$inbox_rate*100),0)
df$received_dt <- as.character(df$received_dt)
df$received_dt <- as.Date(df$received_dt, "%Y%m%d")
df <- df[order(df$received_dt),]

## This second block here is where I'm trying to build the chart with two Y-axes
hc <- highchart()%>%
hc_title(text = paste(domain_name,sep=""),align = "center") %>%
hc_legend(align = "center") %>%
hc_xAxis(type = "datetime", labels = list(format = '{value:%m/%d}')) %>%
hc_yAxis_multiples(list(title = list(text = "IPR"),labels=list(format = '{value}%'),min=0,
    max=100,showFirstLabel = TRUE,showLastLabel=TRUE,opposite = FALSE),
    list(title = list(text = "Total Subscribers"),min=0,max = max(df$total_users),
    labels = list(format = "{value}"),showLastLabel = FALSE, opposite = TRUE)) %>%
hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal")) %>%
hc_add_series(df,"column",hcaes(
  x=received_dt,y=total_users,group=isp,yAxis=total_users)) %>%
hc_add_series(df,type="line",hcaes(
  x=received_dt,y=inbox_rate,group=isp,yAxis=inbox_rate)) %>%   
hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE) %>%
hc_add_theme(thm)
hc
```

However this produces [something that looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scPHI.png).

To give more insight about the data I'm using, the `domain_name` is a string variable that looks like this: `example.com`. The `total_users` variable is a number that varies from 0 to about 50000. The `received_dt` variable is a date, formatted using `as.Date(df$received_dt, "%Y%m%d")`. The `inbox_rate` variable is a percent, from 0 to 100.

The bar counts are all displaying to the full height of the graph, even though the values of the bars vary widely. To reiterate, I want the right y-axis that the bar chart heights are based on to be the count of the `df$total_users`. Within the hc_yAxis_multiples function, there are two lists given. I thought that the first list gives the left y-axis, and the second gives the right. The closest answer to my question that I could find was given by [this stackoverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084416/two-y-axis-in-highcharter-in-r)

If anyone has any insight, it would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Please add some data to fill in your variables, such that people don't have to guess what your `df`, `domain_name`, `thm`, `received_dt` look like. Any representative mock data is enough.

Comment: I added some insight about the data I'm using. I hope that clears up any confusion.

Comment: No. And thats because confusion is not the main issue. Its about you wanting help and therefore also you providing code snippets that can be run by anyone who views this thread. If I have to spend 15 Minutes to find out what "already formatted the way I want" means and to make my own dataset with my own sample data, then I just get angry and leave this question. If you ever ask yourself why nobody provided an answer yet.

Comment: I do apologize for that. I have added more information in the code block that I posted showing how I calculate my variables and how I formatted `received_dt`. Hope that is more in line with what would be useful for folks who are looking to help.

Answer (score 4):

Your use of the `yAxis` statement in `hc_add_series` seems to be off. First, it should not be inside `hcaes` and second, it's a number specifying which axis (in order of appearance in `hy_yAxis_multiple` call) the series belongs to. So `hc_add_series(..., yAxis = 1)` should be used to assign a series to the second (right) axis.

Below is a (fully self-explaining, independent, minimal) example that shows how it should work.

```
library(highcharter)

df <- data.frame(
  total_inbox = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  total_volume = c(30, 30, 30, 30, 30),
  total_users = c(300, 400, 20, 340, 330),
  received_dt = c("20180202", "20180204", "20180206", "20180210", "20180212"),
  isp = "ProviderXY"
)

df$inbox_rate <- df$total_inbox / df$total_volume
df$inbox_rate <- round((df$inbox_rate*100),0)
df$received_dt <- as.character(df$received_dt)
df$received_dt <- as.Date(df$received_dt, "%Y%m%d")
df <- df[order(df$received_dt),]

hc <- highchart()%>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime", labels = list(format = '{value:%m/%d}')) %>%
  hc_yAxis_multiples(list(title = list(text = "IPR"),labels=list(format = '{value}%'),min=0,
                          max=100,showFirstLabel = TRUE,showLastLabel=TRUE,opposite = FALSE),
                     list(title = list(text = "Total Subscribers"),min=0,max = max(df$total_users),
                          labels = list(format = "{value}"),showLastLabel = FALSE, opposite = TRUE)) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal")) %>%
  hc_add_series(df,type="column",hcaes(x=received_dt,y=total_users,group=isp),yAxis=1) %>%
  hc_add_series(df,type="line",hcaes(x=received_dt,y=inbox_rate,group=isp))

hc
```

Maybe take this as an example how code in questions should be like. Copy-Paste-Runnable, no outside variables and minus all the things that dont matter here (like the theme and legend for example).

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes this is a a big help. And also thank you for bearing with me, I will do my best to follow your example to make sure I abide standard expectations in the future (this was my first time asking a q on stack overflow).

Comment: The graph looks much better. The one lingering issue I have now in my code is that that the left y-axis is now going up to 120%, even though I have the max set to 100. In the example you provided, that is not happening even though the highcharter code is essentially identical. I don't know what could have changed to cause this. I will update this post with findings if I figure it out.

Comment: @P.Lawlor Ticks are calculated based on data of both axis together. So the length of a tick on the percentage axis might not be a divider of 100, ergo not adding up to making 100% a tick. (Rather 105% being a tick for example, if every tick is 15% height.) You can avoid or reshape the axis by adding a fixed `tickAmount`. I would choose `tickAmount=11` **on both y-axis**. (Thus overwriting the internal calculation process.)

Comment: Thank you again! I changed it to 5 and it fixed it based on the example I was working with, but I will change it to 11 in case other examples calculate differently.