# Setting up dual axes labels for error bar plots in highcharts using highcharter in R

Tags: r, highcharts, errorbar, r-highcharter

I am looking to create a plot consist of scatter plot and horizontal error bar in highcharts using the [highcharter](http://jkunst.com/highcharter/index.html) package in R. I am hoping to have two y-axis labels on the plot where the left side will show the names of each error bar and the right side will be the value of the error bars.

Based on [here](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084416/two-y-axis-in-highcharter-in-r), I know it is possible to create dual axes label for the Y-axis. However, in order to get the error bars to be horizontal, I have to **invert/flip** the axes (error bars in highcharts are vertical). For that reason, what I will need is actually to have dual **X-axis** labels and then flip the coordinates.

I included the code I have so far that creates the scatter plot and horizontal error bar as well as having the names on the left side.

Thank!

```
# load pacakge ---------------
if(!require(tidyverse)) {install.packages("tidyverse"); library(tidyverse)}
if(!require(magrittr)) {install.packages("magrittr"); library(magrittr)}
if(!require(highcharter)) {install.packages("highcharter"); library(highcharter)}

# sample data
dd <- read.table(textConnection("Abbreviation   Adjustment  Effect  x_dummy lwr_final   med_final   upr_final
PBO A   AA  0   7.37    12.7    18.82
PBO A   BB  2   1.77    9.91    40.32
PBO B   AA  4   7.37    12.7    18.82
PBO B   BB  6   1.77    9.91    40.32
ABP A   AA  1   3.07    4.63    6.89
ABP A   BB  3   0.26    1.72    7.35
ABP B   AA  5   3.07    4.63    6.89
ABP B   BB  7   0.26    1.72    7.35
"), header = T)

# create group column
dd %<>%
  mutate(grp1 = paste0(Adjustment, " (", Effect, ")"))

# category label for plot from 
cat_lab <- dd %>%
  dplyr::group_by(name = Abbreviation) %>%
  dplyr::do(categories = array(.$grp1)) %>%
  highcharter::list_parse()

# creating plot
pp <- highcharter::hchart(dd, "errorbar",
                         highcharter::hcaes(x = x_dummy, low = lwr_final, high = upr_final),
                         color = "black", whiskerLength = 5) %>%
  highcharter::hc_add_series(dd, "scatter",
                             highcharter::hcaes(x = x_dummy, y = med_final),
                             marker = list(radius = 2),
                             color = "red") %>%
  highcharter::hc_xAxis(categories = cat_lab) %>%
  # flip coordinates
  highcharter::hc_chart(inverted = TRUE)
pp
```

Comment: Hi! Could you give me a draw of your requirement? I think your question is easy, but I don't know what exactly you want to achieve and, to avoid wrong naming and misleading, it would be best to see the final result. Even primitive Paint should do the job ;)

Comment: Hi @raf18seb thank you for you reply!

[This is how the plot looks like currently based on the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5tRc.png) and 

[This is what I would like the plot to look like ultimately](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ur3Lx.png).

But the labels/text on the right side would be different. They would be the actual value of the red dot on the graph as well as the lower/upper bound of the error bar.

Comment: Hi, sorry for a late reply. Do you know pure JS? I have prepared a simplified example of inverted chart with 2 xAxis on the opposite sides, but I am not so good with R and it's hard for me to rewrite it: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tfvr8ekh
If you want to display different values in xAxis, you can use xAxis.labels.formatter