# Adding a second x-axis in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, r-highcharter

*NOTE: the below code is for Highcharts in R, but obviously any solution in 'normal' Highcharts code is also more than welcome!*

I'm trying to print the mean (indicated by the diamond symbol in the example, below), and a difference to benchmark (not included in the sample data below) to a horizontal stacked bar chart.

At first I thought to plot a second graph, and combine them with `hw_grid`, but aligning them is really tricky. Hence I thought I'd add the numbers as the labels on a second x-axis.

I know it's possible to add multiple y-axes ([Two y Axis in Highcharter in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084416/two-y-axis-in-highcharter-in-r), and https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes), but because this is a horizontal chart, it needs to be the x-axis, and there doesn't seem to be an equivalent?

Here's the dummy data to reproduce in `R`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)

df1 = data.frame("label"= paste0("Label", c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)), 
                "value" = c(-100,231,110, -189,299,198, -199,150,298, -90,180,155), 
                "grade" = rep(c("Disagree","Neutral","Agree"), 4))

df2 = data.frame("x" = c(0,1,2,3), 
                 "y" = c(200,100,250,280))

highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(df1, type="bar", hcaes(x=label,y=value,group=grade)) %>%
  hc_add_series(df2, type="scatter", marker=list(symbol='diamond', radius=8)) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(bar = list(stacking="normal")) %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
  hc_yAxis(visible=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works just the same as with the y-axis: simply add another axis object to the xAxis array (being sure to set opposite = true for it) and then for the series you want to leverage it, specify xAxis = 1.

Here is an example (which is using categorical x-axis values but that need not be the case):

```
xAxis: [{
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    crosshair: true
},
{
    categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6',
        '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'],
        opposite: true
}]

...

series: [{
    name: 'Rainfall',
    type: 'column',
    xAxis: 1, // this applies this data to the alternate (2nd axis) specified above
    data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' mm'
    }

}, {
    name: 'Temperature',
    type: 'spline',
    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '°C'
    }
}]
```

In this example, you can even have 2 x-axes and 2 y-axes:
https://jsfiddle.net/mzhukovs/8v167bcf/2/

Comment: Wow okay, embarrassingly simple in the end. I guess I'd gotten lost in trying functions like `hc_yAxis_multiples` that don't have an `xAxis` alternative.. Thanks!